# Cluster authorization error while connecting to kafka 2.7 with flink 1.16

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to connect to kafka 2.7 with flink 1.16 ( flink-connector-kafka version 1.16 as well), but I'm getting cluster authorization error.

I tried connecting to that same kafka with flink 1.14 and it worked with the same exact code.

I read in the release notes of 1.16 that thekafka connector now uses kafka client 3.1.1 by default, but I'm not sure if this is my problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue as u, have u solved it already?

Comment: Yes, adding kafka-clients dependancy to my pom.xml solved my problem.